# Как изолировать Ubuntu от Windows

Tags: linux, windows, консоль, ntfs, ext4

На ноутбуке **Lenovo z580**, параллельно установлены две `OS`

- `Ubuntu 17.04 x86_64`
- `Windows 10 64 bit`

HDD размечен на такие разделы:

`ext4` разделы `Linux`

- `/`
- `/home`

отдельно

- `/swap`

`NTFS` разделы `Windows`

- `/sda2` - является диском `С:\`
- `/sda3` - является диском `D:\`

При работе в `Ubuntu` можно зайти на разделы - `/dev/sda2` и `/dev/sda3` через консоль. Считывать и записывать информацию. Так же  можно производить монтирование и размонтирование разделов.

Прошу подсказать мне:

1. Как *изолировать* `Ubuntu` от `Windows`?
2. как скрыть разделы `/dev/sda2` и `/dev/sda3` от `Ubuntu` ?
3. как сделать, что бы `Ubuntu` видела только `ext4` разделы `/home` и `/` ?

Comment: К чему такие извращения? Вряд ли это будет возможно без виртуальной машины

Comment: Не совсем понятно, чего вы хотите добиться в конечном счёте. Почему бы просто пользователям Ubuntu не выдавать прав на монтирование ненужных разделов?

Comment: Разделы монтируются автоматически при старте Ubuntu. Их можно размонтировать, но они все равно видны в файловом менеджере.  Понятно что при команде df в консоль покажется вся информация о разделах. В конечном счете хотелось бы, что бы при старте Ubuntu, ОС видела только свои разделы и могла работать только с ними.

Answer (score 2):

Итак данное решение заключается в том, что бы скрыть интересующий раздел, и без прав доступа root, пользователь не сможет работать с скрытым разделом.

На своем примере - скрываю раздел `sda2`:

- Открываем  `terminal`
- `sudo -s`
- Вводим пароль
- Размонтирование раздела `sda2` командой `umount /dev/sda2`
- Выводим информацию  о разделе в `teminal` командой `udisksctl info -b /dev/sda2`
- Ищем строку `IdUUID` в  моем случае это `IdUUID - D44E1A684E1A43A0`
- `nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-hide-partitions.rules`
- Вставляем строку:

  `SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="D44E1A684E1A43A0", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"`
- Сохраняем
- Перезагружаем ОС

Если набрать в терминале команду `df -h` скрытый раздел не виден.

Важно - не забудьте вставить именно Ваш `IdUUID` раздела.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете скрыть раздел при помощи утилиты "Диски" (Disks). Выберите нужный раздел, кликните на кнопку с шестерёнками, выберите "Изменить параметры подключения" и там снимите галку "Подключать при запуске". Более подробно [тут](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124094/how-to-hide-an-ntfs-partition-from-ubuntu).

Comment: Beast Winterwolf огромное спасибо, ответ найден

Comment: Но это по-прежнему позволит набрать `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/чтототам` через консольку (хотя, видимо, автора это устраивает)

Comment: @andreymal всё верно, или через ту же самую утилиту disks можно проделать обратную операцию. Это решение позволяет скрыть раздел, но не затрагивает права доступа.

Comment: @andreymal если у вас есть доступ к sudo, то о чём вообще речь? Вы в праве делать что угодно в таком случае. Те пользователи, от которых разделы скрываются, обычно такими правами не обладают.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf ну, в заголовке написано «Как изолировать **Ubuntu** от Windows», а не «Как изолировать пользователя», разрешаю считать меня занудой :)

Comment: @andreymal если так в штыки воспринимать вопрос, то ответа на него не будет, поскольку ограничить свободу root'у практически невозможно.

Comment: @andreymal занудой Вас считать не буду))  Вы все верно аргументируете, способ скрытия разделов подходит даже очень, нет пароля от sudo - нет монтированию раздела, соответственно никаких действий с ним проделать нельзя. Команда df -h скрытый раздел не показывает.  Очень интересное решение, буду сейчас делать пошаговую инструкцию.